# how to send_keys for div element in python selenium?

Tags: java, python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Below is the the HTML script:

```
<div class="textarea-wrapper">
<div class="textarea" tabindex="0"role="textbox" aria-label="Message text 
input box" placeholder="Type a message..." spellcheck="true" data-
role="message-text-input" ng-keydown="preventReturns($event)" ng-
click="handleOneToOneMessage($event)" ng-
keyup="removeWhitespace();handleOneToOneMessage($event)" ng-blur="onBlur()" 
ng-paste="parsePlainText()" ondrop="return false;" contenteditable="true"/>
</div>
```

The command i am using to send keys to that textarea:

```
mesg_box = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".textarea")
time.sleep(3)
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", mesg_box[0])
mesg_box[0].send_keys("hiii")
```

here `mesg_box` will return 2 items and they are returning fine but I couldn't able to click on the input field may be because it has only div field but not the input field.
The test case is passing fine if the browser in focus.

The above Code is working Fine for chrome(when minimized also) but is failing for Firefox if Firefox is not on focus I mean if Firefox is minimized.

please let me know if there is any solution to send keys for the text area even when Firefox is minimized.

Comment: why are you using javascript to click rather than `click` method provided by selenium?

Comment: Hi Gaurang Shah i already tried using '.click()' but its not working so i checked in forums they told me to use execute_script() method.But its also not working

Comment: are you getting any exception in firefox? if not what exactly happens?

Comment: There is no exception its going to the next line to send-keys and in ui it's not clicking the text area.Even there is no exception in send_keys it going to next line but in UI no operation is pperformed